# Rails - PaperClip & Acts_As_Versioned - Accessing a Photo URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, acts-as-versioned

I've implemented the following:

**File versioning in Ruby on Rails with Paperclip & acts_as_versioned:**
[http://eggsonbread.com/2009/07/23/file-versioning-in-ruby-on-rails-with-paperclip-acts_as_versioned/][1]

When you upload a new photo it is now successfully being version. The issue I'm having is that I can't grab the image  with paperclip:

```
<% for version in @photos.first.versions.reverse %> 
<%= version.photo.inspect %>
<%= image_tag(version.photo.photo(:thumb)) %>
<% end %>
```

Which the "version.photo.inspect" shows the right info, when I call it in the image tag to show the photo, it's always showing the most recent version and not the older version.

Ideas?

Comment: shouldn't that be the case with acts as versioned? it should pull the neewest version